# Passing HTML tags with Python

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

i'm currently working on a proyect that involve **"markdown2"** librarie to transform **.MD** files to **HTML tags**. Almost everything works, but when i render HTML file in python and throw the content of .MD file converted, it just shows the literal tags.
Here is the function that **take the MD file and read it**:

```
def get_entry(title):
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

And here is the function that **convert the MD file, pass those HTML tags and render the HTML file**:

```
def entry(request, title):
    entry = markdown(util.get_entry(title))
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "entry" : entry
    })
```

Here is the **HTML file**:

```
{% extends 'encyclopedia/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}

{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
{{ entry }}
{% endblock %}
```

In  the browser it shows the HTML file withe converted MD files like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn0oL.png)

**¿How can i pass those HTML tags so the browser understand that they are tags and not strings?**

Comment: I FIXED IT. Just put ```{{ entry|safe }}```

Comment: Do you have an example of the markdown file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django automatically escapes HTML special characters for security reasons, see their docs on [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape).

When your template variable contains HTML code you need to mark it as safe using the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template filter and make sure yourself that any dangerous content (e.g. user input) is filtered:

```
{% block body %}
    {{ entry|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```